# Transform: translate bug (pixel gaps at certain resolutions)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Take a look at the following code:

```css
#wrapper{
  /*set the size of the box*/
  width:40%;
  margin:0 auto 20px;
}

#ratio{
  /*parent is a 16:9 DIV*/
  padding-top:56.25%;
  position:relative;
  
  background:aqua;
}

img{
  display:block;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  
  /*the fun part: vertically+horizontally center it*/
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="ratio">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="ratio">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x350">
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the DIV has a dynamic width and height, which makes it hard to deal with. On browsers like firefox and chrome, you can clearly see a 0 to 1 pixel gap when resizing a certain way. I feel like I tried everything (been troubleshooting this for days at this point).

Any tips or alternatives? I'd rather have a pure CSS solution but javascript ones are also welcome.